# The hourly mean in time series

Tags: r, time-series

this is a time series with hourly smart meter data and freq=24. It is measured over three days, so `first day[1:24], second[25:48], third[49:72].`

I want to have the mean for every hour over three days. For example:

```
(t[1]+t[25]+t[49])/3
```

so I can make a boxplot for 24 mean hours over 3 days.

```
x <- c(0.253, 0.132, 0.144, 0.272, 0.192, 0.132, 0.209, 0.255, 0.131, 
  0.136, 0.267, 0.166, 0.139, 0.238, 0.236, 1.75, 0.32, 0.687, 
  0.528, 1.198, 1.961, 1.171, 0.498, 1.28, 2.267, 2.605, 2.776, 
  4.359, 3.062, 2.264, 1.212, 1.809, 2.536, 2.48, 0.531, 0.515, 
  0.61, 0.867, 0.804, 2.282, 3.016, 0.998, 2.332, 0.612, 0.785, 
  1.292, 2.057, 0.396, 0.455, 0.283, 0.131, 0.147, 0.272, 0.198, 
  0.13, 0.19, 0.257, 0.149, 0.134, 0.251, 0.215, 0.133, 1.755, 
  1.855, 1.938, 1.471, 0.528, 0.842, 0.223, 0.256, 0.239, 0.113)
```

Comment: The modulus operator `%%` will be of use, eg `1%%24 = 25%%24 = 49%%24`

Answer (score 10):

Because you did not post an easy to use set of example data, let's first generate some:

```
time_series = runif(72)
```

The next step would be to change the structure of the dataset from a 1d vector, to a 2d matrix, this saves you a lot of having to deal with indices and such:

```
time_matrix = matrix(time_series, 24, 3)
```

and use `apply` to calculate the hourly means (if you like `apply`, take a look at the `plyr` package for more nice functions, see [this link](http://www.jstatsoft.org/v40/i01/paper) for more detail):

```
hourly_means = apply(time_matrix, 1, mean)
> hourly_means
 [1] 0.2954238 0.6791355 0.6113670 0.5775792 0.3614329 0.4414882 0.6206761
 [8] 0.2079882 0.6238492 0.4069143 0.6333607 0.5254185 0.6685191 0.3629751
[15] 0.3715500 0.2637383 0.2730713 0.3170541 0.6053016 0.6550780 0.4031117
[22] 0.6857810 0.4492246 0.4795785
```

However, if you use `ggplot2` there is no need to precalculate the boxplots, `ggplot2` does this for you:

```
require(ggplot2)
require(reshape2)
# Notice the use of melt to reshape the dataset a bit
# Also notice the factor to transform Var1 to a categorical dataset
ggplot(aes(x = factor(Var1), y = value), 
       data = melt(time_matrix)) + 
       geom_boxplot()
```

Which yields, what I think, you where after:

[image]

On the x-axis the hours of the day, on the y axis the value.

---

Note: the data you have is a timeseries. R has specific ways of dealing with timeseries, e.g. the `ts` function. I normally use ordinary R data objects (array's, matrices), but you could take a look at the [TimeSeries CRAN taskview](http://cran.r-project.org/web/views/TimeSeries.html) for an overview of what R can do with timeseries.

To calculate the hourly means using a `ts` object (inspired by this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6529981/calculate-monthly-average-of-ts-object)):

```
# Create a ts object
time_ts = ts(time_series, frequency = 24)
# Calculate the mean
> tapply(time_ts, cycle(time_ts), mean)
        1         2         3         4         5         6         7         8 
0.2954238 0.6791355 0.6113670 0.5775792 0.3614329 0.4414882 0.6206761 0.2079882 
        9        10        11        12        13        14        15        16 
0.6238492 0.4069143 0.6333607 0.5254185 0.6685191 0.3629751 0.3715500 0.2637383 
       17        18        19        20        21        22        23        24 
0.2730713 0.3170541 0.6053016 0.6550780 0.4031117 0.6857810 0.4492246 0.4795785 
> aggregate(as.numeric(time_ts), list(hour = cycle(time_ts)), mean)
   hour         x
1     1 0.2954238
2     2 0.6791355
3     3 0.6113670
4     4 0.5775792
....
```

Comment: Better yet, `rowMeans(matrix(time_series, 24, 3))`. +1 for the quick answer!

Comment: Thanks for the comment, I thought splitting it out into a twoline would make it easier to read for the OP. In addition, `apply` is a bit more general, making it more instructive to the OP. But I agree, `rowMeans` is a better function.

Answer (score 3):

You can do this easily with the `boxplot` function that comes with a basic R installation.  Just create a data.frame with your original series and an index to identify the hour of each day.

```
Data <- data.frame(series=x, time=rep(1:24,3))
boxplot(series ~ time, data=Data)
```

[image: boxplot output]