# Monthly summary of a time series in r

Tags: r

This a newbie question in R. I have a time series object and I want to create monthly summary (i.e. mean median mode) for the series. I want this to be a vector. Example below:

```
ddd<-c(1:100)
ddd1<-ts(ddd,frequency=12,start=c(1960,1))
```

What I need is the average value for the month of January, February, etc. it is a 12X1 vector with values. For January, February, and March it is 49, 50,51 respectively.  One  long way to do this is to use the seasondummy() function of the forecast package and do  regression to get the result,  but I am looking for an elegant solution. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might be a bit clunky, and I'm sure there is a better `zoo` function for this, but in the spirit of learning something, you can do this with base R functions working on a `ts` object:

```
window(ddd1, c(1960,1), deltat=1)
```

...will start at `1960.1` (January) and extract a value every 12 months (deltat=12/12=1), which means you can then `sapply` this function like:

```
sapply(1:12, function(x) mean(window(ddd1, c(1960,x), deltat=1)) )
#[1] 49 50 51 52 47 48 49 50 51 52 53 54
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use `tapply`, it is useful to apply a function across a vector grouping by the values in another vector

```
> v<-rnorm(48)  #our fake values
> mos<-rep(1:12,4)  # our months, jan=1, feb=2 etc, for 4 years
> tapply(v, mos, mean) #take the mean of values in vector v by mos
            1             2             3             4             5 
-0.7616624170 -0.4196531309  0.1366554601 -0.1670395139 -0.0954241388 
            6             7             8             9            10 
 0.1867522250 -0.1505984224 -0.0897725216 -0.0005245822 -0.0870436711 
           11            12 
 0.5518353674 -0.0652350665
```

applying this to your example, you can make your groupings by looking at month %% 12 (month mod 12), s.t december = 0, jan =1 etc

```
> ddd1 %% 12
     Jan Feb Mar Apr May Jun Jul Aug Sep Oct Nov Dec
1960   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9  10  11   0
1961   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9  10  11   0
1962   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9  10  11   0
1963   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9  10  11   0
1964   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9  10  11   0
1965   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9  10  11   0
1966   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9  10  11   0
1967   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9  10  11   0
1968   1   2   3   4                                
> tapply(ddd,ddd1 %% 12, mean)
 0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 
54 49 50 51 52 47 48 49 50 51 52 53
```

And my favorite version: using `plyr` library

```
> ddply(data.frame(mo=ddd1%%12, val=ddd), .(mo), summarize, mean=mean(val), median=median(val), min=min(val), max=max(val))
   mo mean median min max
1   0   54     54  12  96
2   1   49     49   1  97
3   2   50     50   2  98
4   3   51     51   3  99
5   4   52     52   4 100
6   5   47     47   5  89
7   6   48     48   6  90
8   7   49     49   7  91
9   8   50     50   8  92
10  9   51     51   9  93
11 10   52     52  10  94
12 11   53     53  11  95
```

You can recreate the same results (although in list form) using `tapply` as follows, but I tend to find the output of a `data.frame` from `ddply` to be more amenable for further analysis

```
tapply(ddd, ddd1%%12, function(x) c(mean=mean(x), median=median(x), min=min(x), max=max(x)))
```

Comment: Just saw the following link, very similar to the above. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6529981/calculate-monthly-average-of-ts-object?rq=1