# How to calculate the average year

Tags: r

I have a 20-year monthly XTS time series

Jan 1990  12.3

Feb 1990  45.6

Mar 1990  78.9

..

Jan 1991  34.5

..

Dec 2009  89.0

I would like to get the average (12-month) year, or

Jan   xx

Feb   yy

...

Dec   kk

where xx is the average of every January, yy of every February, and so on.

I have tried apply.yearly and lapply but these return 1 value, which is the 20-year total average

Would you have any suggestions?  I appreciate it.

Comment: You could find useful [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6530023/1315767) additionally you can plot them using `monthplot()`

Comment: Thank you. Jilber.  That post had what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `lubridate` package could be useful for you. I would use the functions `year()` and `month()` in conjunction with `aggregate()`:

```
library(xts)
library(lubridate)

#set up some sample data
dates = seq(as.Date('2000/01/01'), as.Date('2005/01/01'), by="month")
df = data.frame(rand1 = runif(length(dates)), rand2 = runif(length(dates)))
my_xts = xts(df, dates) 

#get the mean by year
aggregate(my_xts$rand1, by=year(index(my_xts)), FUN=mean)
```

This outputs something like:

```
2000 0.5947939
2001 0.4968154
2002 0.4941752
2003 0.5291211
2004 0.6631564
```

To find the mean for each month you can do:

```
#get the mean by month
aggregate(my_xts$rand1, by=month(index(my_xts)), FUN=mean)
```

which will output something like

```
1  0.5560279
2  0.6352220
3  0.3308571
4  0.6709439
5  0.6698147
6  0.7483192
7  0.5147294
8  0.3724472
9  0.3266859
10 0.5331233
11 0.5490693
12 0.4642588
```

Comment: Thank you, dfriend21, for the detailed answer to my question.