# Why i cant see the number of month in ts object

Tags: r, time-series

I have this `ts()` object:

```
ts(Df, start = c(2010, 7), end = c(2022, 11),frequency = 12)
```

but when I try to see the time window it appears as follows:

```
time(Df_ts)
```

> 2010.500 2010.583 2010.667 2010.750 2010.833 2010.917

I am expecting it to be:

> 2010.7 2010.8 2010.9

Comment: I think you want `cycle(Df_ts)` as discussed here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6529981/calculate-monthly-average-of-ts-object

Answer (score 1):

The reason is the `frequency` of your ts object is set to 12. This means that time stamps in your ts object are evenly spaced at intervals of `1 month`. Example, time stamp for Jan.1 2010 is 2010.000, time stamp for Feb.1  2010 is 2010.083. If you'd like to see number of month in your ts object you can use `as.yearmon()` function. Following converts your ts object to yearmon object:

```
library(zoo)
Df_ts_yearmon <- as.yearmon(Df.ts)
```

Then you use `time()` function to see the time stamps:

```
time(Df_ts_yearmon[1:6])
```

Answer (score 1):

No, it starts with `.0`, not with `.1.`. It's one twelfth of a year. January has `0/12`, February `1/12`, etc.

```
1/12
# [1] 0.08333333

ts(1:10, start = c(2010, 1), end=c(2011, 1), frequency=12) |> time()
#           Jan      Feb      Mar      Apr      May      Jun
# 2010 2010.000 2010.083 2010.167 2010.250 2010.333 2010.417
# 2011 2011.000                                             
#           Jul      Aug      Sep      Oct      Nov      Dec
# 2010 2010.500 2010.583 2010.667 2010.750 2010.833 2010.917
# 2011
```

This is the same logic:

```
seq.int(2010, 2011, length.out=13)
#  [1] 2010.000 2010.083 2010.167 2010.250 2010.333 2010.417
#  [7] 2010.500 2010.583 2010.667 2010.750 2010.833 2010.917
# [13] 2011.000
```